# Make div fill all browser height without child div overflow parent

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with div heights.

I have something like this:

```css
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid red; //Just to show area
  height: 70px;
 }
 
 .main {
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
 }
 
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
 }
 
.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    Navbar
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid main row">
    <div class="sidebar col-3">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="content col-9">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the main div and its childs to fill all browser when the content is shorter than the browser height. And when the content gets higher than the browser I want the main and sidebar divs to get as high as content div with scroll bar.

But I can't make those two situations work.

1 - I set navbar height to 70px and used calc to set main height so the main div fill all browser height. But when the content div is higher than the browser height it overflow its parent and sidebar doesn't follow content height.

Like this:

[image]

2 - When I don't set those heights it works fine when the content is taller than the browser. The main div and sidebar gets as high as content div. But when the content is short, main div doesn't fill the entire browser height.

Like this:

[image]

I read a lot of answers, posts, blogs, everything that I do results in one case working but the other not.

What should I do?

Comment: follow bootstrap rules .. row inside container

Comment: You might want to have a look into `css grid` - theres a great way to get started here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ - and it allows you to use units like `1fr` (_all the free space please!_)

Comment: @TemaniAfif good to know. I thought that putting them in the same div worked. So it has be row inside container right?

Comment: yes row inside container, then you are using the V4 of bootstrap that rely on flexbox so what you want to achieve is easy if you read the documentation and you see the utilities classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: I'm working with bootstrap grid system. I was looking to do something like @somethinghere said.
I tought of using flexbox. I get confused when it's better to use grid and when I should use flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed the comment from your css code and changed `height` to `min-height` and it works. Try this code.

```
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 70px;
}

.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: happy to help, keep coding